# Is there a way of generating random numbers from an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` that contains numbers (1-50). Now I want to generate random numbers from this `ArrayList` (each random number must be an item from the `ArrayList`) and once that item is picked, it will be remove from the `ArrayList`.

This is what I have tried but the `Random` object keeps generating numbers that are not in the `ArrayList`

```
Random rnd = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    
while (list2.size() < 50) {
    int index = list1.get(rnd.nextInt(list1.size()));
    list2.add(index);
    list1.remove(index);
}
```

The above code keeps generating random numbers that are not in the `list1` object.

I need only numbers that are in `list1` to be generated.

Comment: If so, please show your method `list1`.

Comment: I'm honestly stumped as to how this isn't working and I think I'd like to see more of your code. Because the `rnd.nextInt()` you have there *should* be returning you a number between 0 and 49.
That being said, your `list1.remove()` may be removing the wrong number. In this case, if your random number was 29, you'd be adding a 30 to list2 (because that's what's at index 29 of list1) but removing the 31 from list1 (because that's what's at index 30, which is what `index` is set to now)

Comment: @Raphael Morgan: That's the point, the **rnd.nextInt()** generates any number between 0 and 49 but this is not what i want. The number it has to generate must be an element in list1 object

Comment: I know, but you aren't removing the object you queried. the rnd.nextInt gets you an index, and the object you want at that index (what you're setting to "index") is what's being added to list2 but NOT what's being added to list1. It's trying to remove the number at that index, not that number. Eg list1.remove(50) wouldn't work even if the #50 is in the list because the indices are 0-49 at most.

Comment: How do you know the random is picking up numbers that aren't in the list? Can you give us more context?

Comment: @Maurice Perry: it is list1.get()

Comment: @Raphael Morgan: i now understand that the **rnd.nextInt()** deals with index of a value but not the actual value itself which means... if i'm sending **list1.remove(10)** , value 10 is not removed but a value at index 10. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are picking a random number from one list, removing it (note that there's a difference in `remove(Integer o)` and `remove(int index)`) , and inserting into another.

This is the exact same operation as shuffling the original list, making a copy, then clearing it

```
List<Integer> list1 = IntStream.range(1,51).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(list1);
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
list1.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while (list2.size() < 50) {
    int index = rnd.nextInt(list1.size());
    list2.add(list1.remove(index));
}
```

UPDATE:

BTW: `index` is an `int`, not an `Integer`, so `list1.remove(index)` removes the element at given index, and not the element with given value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simply shuffle the original list.

```
List<SomeObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.shuffle(objects);
```

Now, take the value from the end (more efficient for `ArrayLists`), and then delete it.

```
int last = objects.size()-1;
while (last >= 0) {
     SomeObject ob = objects.get(last);
     objects.remove(last--);
     // now do whatever you want with ob
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to the line #7:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    
while (list2.size() < 50) {
    int index = list1.get(rnd.nextInt(list1.size()));
    list2.add(index); <-- you are adding random index here instead of list1's value
    list1.remove(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the issue solved by shuffling the `list1` object before putting them to `list2`

```
Collection.shuffle(list1);
for (int i=0; i<=50; i++){
    list2.put(list1(i);
}
```

This gave me exactly what i wanted.
Thanks everyone for your contributions